# How to increase or decrease flakiness retry for hypothesis?

Tags: python-hypothesis

Hypothesis tries a test example 3 times if the test example initially fails.

eg

> Flaky: Hypothesis ... 
>   produces unreliable results: Falsified on the first call but did not
>   on a subsequent one

Is there a way to increase or decrease the number of tries?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not a configurable setting.

Why would you want to change it?  There might be something else that would solve your problem.